# Fix an image to top when the user scroll - Jquery Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I am making a personal website, it's a one-page website, I want that when the user scrolls down to 'about' or 'contact us' the image on the home page sticks right below the navbar, navbar here is also fixed. 
How do I do it using jquery scroll?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask a good question so it will be easier us to help you.

Comment: Why are you not using position:fixed for the image too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too simple in CSS. You have to use

```
.imageClassName{
 position : fixed;
 top:0;
 }
```